# Python solve delay differential equations conditionally

Tags: python, c, scipy, differential-equations

I am using `dde23` of `pydelay` package to solve a delay differential equation. My question: How to code a equation conditionally? For example the target equation has two options:

```
when x>1, dx/dt=0.25 * x(t-tau) / (1.0 + pow(x(t-tau),10.0)) -0.1*x
otherwise, dx/dt=0.25 * x
```

I tried two approaches, but it seems like neither one worked:

1. Approach 1 did not complain, but it the if else statement has not
   been interpreted.
2. Approach 2 generated the following errors:

   Found executable c:\mingw\bin\g++.exe
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp: In function 'double f(double, double)':
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:734: error: 'x' cannot be used as a function
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:734: error: 'x' cannot be used as a function
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp: In function 'PyObject* compiled_func(PyObject*, PyObject*)':
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:878: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:883: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:774: warning: unused variable 'Nhistx_ar'
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:775: warning: unused variable 'Shistx_ar'
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:776: warning: unused variable 'Dhistx_ar'
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:785: warning: unused variable 'NVhistx_ar'
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:786: warning: unused variable 'SVhistx_ar'
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:787: warning: unused variable 'DVhistx_ar'
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:796: warning: unused variable 'NThist_ar'
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:797: warning: unused variable 'SThist_ar'
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:798: warning: unused variable 'DThist_ar'
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:817: warning: unused variable 'Ndiscont'
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:818: warning: unused variable 'Sdiscont'
   c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp:819: warning: unused variable 'Ddiscont'
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Documents and Settings\thao\Desktop\mackey-glass.py", line 33, in 
       dde.run()
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydelay_dde23.py", line 1120, in run
       compiler = 'gcc')
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\inline_tools.py", line 355, in inline
       **kw)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\inline_tools.py", line 482, in compile_function
       verbose=verbose, **kw)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\ext_tools.py", line 367, in compile
       verbose = verbose, **kw)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\build_tools.py", line 272, in build_extension
       setup(name = module_name, ext_modules = [ext],verbose=verb)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 186, in setup
       return old_setup(**new_attr)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
       raise SystemExit, "error: " + str(msg)
   distutils.errors.CompileError: error: Command "g++ -O2 -Wall -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\scxx -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.cpp -o c:\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_intermediate\compiler_a77d1132635f0379270bcb96a5e542fc\Release\docume~1\thao\locals~1\temp\thong\python27_compiled\sc_f68f7a878bf7b27c6f72c9e771ec4d311.o" failed with exit status 1
   [Finished in 5.8s with exit code 1]

#### Approach 1 (use the if else statement to update `eqns` which is a python dict):

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from pydelay import dde23

eqn_1a='0.25 * x(t-tau) / (1.0 + pow(x(t-tau),10.0)) -0.1*x'
eqn_1b='0.45 * x'

eqns = { 'x' : eqn_1a if 'x>1' else eqn_1b}

dde = dde23(eqns=eqns, params={'tau': 15})
dde.set_sim_params(tfinal=1000, dtmax=1.0, AbsTol=10**-6, RelTol=10**-3)

histfunc = {'x': lambda t: 0.5 } 
dde.hist_from_funcs(histfunc, 51)
dde.run()

sol1 = dde.sample(2, 3, 0.1)
x1 = sol1['x']
```

#### Approach 2 (provide c code to the solver):

```
eqns = { 'x' : 'f(x, tau)'}

# We can define a c function to be used in the equations
mycode = """
    double f(double x, double tau) {
        if (x>1){
            return (0.25 * x(t-tau) / (1.0 + pow(x(t-tau),10.0)) -0.1*x);
        }
        else{
            return (0.45 * x);
        }
     }
    """
dde = dde23(eqns=eqns, params={'tau': 15}, supportcode=mycode)

dde.set_sim_params(tfinal=1000, dtmax=1.0, AbsTol=10**-6, RelTol=10**-3)

histfunc = {'x': lambda t: 0.5 } 
dde.hist_from_funcs(histfunc, 51)
dde.run()

sol1 = dde.sample(1, 300, 1)
x1 = sol1['x']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second approach works with one minor change. The value of the delayed variable has to be passed as an argument to the function directly.

```
eqns = { 'x' : 'f(x, x(t - tau))'}

mycode = """
double f(double x, double x_tau) {
    if (x > 1.0){
        return 0.25 * x_tau / (1.0 + pow(x_tau, 10.0)) -0.1*x;
    }
    else{
        return 0.45 * x;
    }
}
"""
```

Although this does run, note that it cannot give a very accurate solution. This is due to the discontinuity at `x=1`. More advanced solvers can explicitly handle such discontinuities (see e.g. http://www.radford.edu/~thompson/ffddes/).

If you want to stick with the pydelay solver for convenience or just to get an overview, you can try to set the maximum step size `dtmax` small enough to reduce the error.