# Solve large system of delay differential equations(DDEs) using pydelay

Tags: python, differential-equations

I'm trying to use [pydelay](http://pydelay.sourceforge.net/) to solve a large system of DDEs as follows:

[image]

My approach seems completely silly. I have tried to write the equation as strings and then join different parts together. here is my attempt:

```
def funcE(n,C,D): 
    '''
    n is 0 .. N number of nodes in connectome
    '''
    En = ['Exc'+str(i)  for i in range(n)]
    In = ['Inh'+str(i)  for i in range(n)]
    E_str = ['' for i in range(n)]
    coffE = ['' for i in range(n)]
    sE = ['' for i in range(n)]
    Se = ['' for i in range(n)]
    Ip = ['P' for i in range(n)]
    #Ip = ['P'+str(i) for i in range(n)]

    for k in range(n):
        coffE[k] = str(1./tauE)+'*(-'+En[k]+'+('+str(kE-rE)+'*'+En[k]+')'
        print coffE    
        exit(0)


    for k in range(n):
        temp2 = []
        temp1 = []
        for l in range(n):
            if (k==l):
                continue
            else:
                temp1.append( str(C[k,l])+'*'+En[l]+'(t-'+str(D[k,l])+')')
        temp2 = '+'.join(temp1)
        sE[k] = str(c1)+'*'+En[k]+'-'+str(c2)+'*'+In[k]+'+'+Ip[k]+'+'+str(eta)+'/'+str(float(n))+'*('+temp2+')'

    for k in range(n):
        Se[k] = '(1./(1+ exp(-'+str(aE)+'*('+sE[k]+'-'+str(thetaE)+')))-'+str(1./(1.+exp(aE*thetaE)))
        E_str[k] = coffE[k]+'*'+Se[k]+')'

    return E_str

#---------------------------------------------------------#
def funcI(n): 
    '''
    n is 0 .. N number of nodes in connectome
    '''
    En = ['Exc'+str(i)  for i in range(n)]
    In = ['Inh'+str(i)  for i in range(n)]
    I_str = ['' for i in range(n)]
    coffI = ['' for i in range(n)]
    sI = ['' for i in range(n)]
    Si = ['' for i in range(n)]
    Iq = ['Q' for i in range(n)]

    for k in range(n):
        coffI[k] = str(1./tauI)+'*(-'+In[k]+'+('+str(kI-rI)+'*'+In[k]+')'

    for k in range(n):
        sI[k] = str(c3)+'*'+En[k]+'-'+str(c4)+'*'+In[k]+'+'+Iq[k]

    for k in range(n):
        Si[k] = '(1./(1+ exp(-'+str(aI)+'*('+sI[k]+'-'+str(thetaI)+')))-'+str(1./(1.+exp(aI*thetaI)))
        I_str[k] = coffI[k]+'*'+Si[k]+')'

    return I_str
#---------------------------------------------------------#
```

where `C` in `ckl` and `D` is `\tau` in equations.
The problem here is the summation part that make the equations very long.
It works for small `N` but useless for large `N` and fill the ram quickly. Thanks for any guide or comment.

**Edit**
f or g is a function like this:

[image]

Comment: What is `pydelay`? Sounds like a library. If so, you should provide a link to it. If that library requires input to be strings of a given format, then you need to generate strings of that format, or you need to find a different library (or write your own solver). Are you sure that it doesn't have some method for directly inputting summations without having to expand them? Read the documentation.

Comment: http://pydelay.sourceforge.net/,  yes it is, it also provides an option that we can feed the equation as a `C` type. like  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457673/python-solve-delay-differential-equations-conditionally/19459888#19459888) . I think It could be a solution.

Comment: Interesting question. Unfortunately I have no experience with that library (though it does look nice). Good luck.

Comment: Shameless self-advertisement: I wrote an [alternative DDE solver for Python](http://github.com/neurophysik/jitcdde) that uses SymPy expressions as an input method. As the SymPy expressions can be composed with Python operations, this should allow you to solve your problem in a less tedious way (also, the integrator is probably faster). Note that this is still in development though.